# How to generate a javascript base class instance from a derived class

Tags: javascript

My application passes instances of a shared base class between two processes, each of which derives separately from the base to specialize behavior. In Process1 I have instances of the derived class from which I need to generate the base class instances to pass to Process2. The following code works but it seems like there should be a more generic way of handling this situation. Any suggestions for how to rewrite generateBase() such that it still works if new attributes are added to base?

```
// base.js included in Process1 and Process2
class base {
    constructor(attribute1, att2) {
        this._a1 = attribute1;
        this._a2 = att2;
    }
}
// derived1.js included only in Process1
class derived1 extends base {
    constructor(a1, a2, a3) {
        super(a1, a2);
        this._a3 = a3;
    }
    generateBase() {
        // base instance to be passed to Process2
        return new base(this._a1, this._a2);
    }                        
    // Other Process1-specific functionality...
}
// derived2.js included only in Process2
class derived2 extends base {
    constructor(a1, a2, a4) {
        super(a1, a2);
        this._a4 = a4;
    }
    // Other Process2-specific functionality...
```

Comment: why you need to get a copy of the base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with as a generic solution. I create a static instance inside base and then use that to walk thru the attributes and build up the new structure.

```
class base {
    constructor(attribute1, att2) {
        this._a1 = attribute1;
        this._a2 = att2;
    }
    static baseInstance = new base(1,2);
    generateBase() {
        let props = {};
        const keys = Object.keys(base.baseInstance);
        for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            props[keys[i]] = this[keys[i]];
        }
        return props;
    }       
}
// derived1.js included only in Process1
class derived1 extends base {
    constructor(a1, a2, a3) {
        super(a1, a2);
        this._a3 = a3;
    }
}
// derived2.js included only in Process2
class derived2 extends base {
    constructor(b, a4) {
        super(1,2);
        Object.assign(this, b);
        this._a4 = a4;
    }
    // Other Process2-specific functionality...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, *derived* is a child of *base*, meaning you can use it as it was a *base* object

```
class base {
    constructor(attribute1, att2) {
        this._a1 = attribute1;
        this._a2 = att2;
    }
}
class derived extends base {
    constructor(a1, a2, a3) {
        super(a1, a2);
        this._a3 = a3;
    }
    generateBase() {
        // became useless
        return this;
    }                        
}
```

Comment: Antonin see edits for clarification. Instances of base are a shared model across 2 processes each of which understands base, but not the classes other processes derive from it.